# ontouchlisteners in textviews

Tags: android

previously i have added a ontouch listener to textviews which will do a custom vibration upon each touch.

however when i hold the textview it will keep playing out the custom vibration.

how do i set it so that it would only vibrate only once per touch even when i am holding on the textview

i tried onclick and a few other listeners but it doesn't do what i want.. as i require the textview to do the vibration on touch as they go from 1 textview to another

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    vibratePattern();
    return true;
}
private void vibratePattern()
{
    Vibrator vibrator;
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    int dot = 100;
    int dash = 250;
    int short_gap = 200;
    int medium_gap = 500;
    int long_gap = 1000;
    long[] pattern101 = {
        0,
        dot, short_gap, dash, short_gap, dot,
        long_gap
    };

    vibrator.vibrate(pattern101, -1);
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your `vibratePattern` method?

Comment: edited my qn to show the vibrate pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something in your `vibratePattern` method, but this should work and vibrate only once if you check for correct action on the event:

```
if (event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If that won't work with multiple views, then you could attach the same listener to all views and check when the `v` reference changes:

```
if (previousView != v) {
    vibratePattern();
    previousView = v;
}
return true;
```

Comment: hmm mine would vibrate once if u touch it once. but i require the user to move from 1 textview to another textview my dragging their fingers over. as such when i touch and hold on to the first textview the vibratepattern would be called repeatedly (i only need it to be called once)

Comment: @benjamin I think you should check for `action` on the event. Please see my answer updated. I'm not sure though if you tap on one view and drag your finger to another view will android call action=down event on the second view.